# array not initialising properly. BasicDBObject not able to create array of BasicDBObject type

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb

```
case 3:
    BasicDBObject []document= new BasicDBObject(); // error             
    DBCollection table1 = db.getCollection("user");
    document[0].put("name", "mkyong");
    document[0].put("age", 30);
    table1.insert(document);
    System.out.println("Collection Inserted successfully");
    break;
```

Not understanding the problem with the initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would get compile time error because the array initialization is not correct.

```
BasicDBObject []document= new BasicDBObject(); //error
```

Basic Array Initialization in java is as below

```
Object objectArr[] = new Object[10];
```

So you have to initialize the array and pass the values in below manner.

```
BasicDBObject []document1= new BasicDBObject[2];

document1[0] = new BasicDBObject();
document1[0].put("name", "mkyong12");
document1[0].put("age", 30);

document1[1] = new BasicDBObject();
document1[1].put("name", "test12");
document1[1].put("age", 44);
```

**You have to make sure each array object should be initialized otherwise you fail with NullPointerException**

Hope this helps.

Comment: If it answers your question please mark it as answered

Answer (score 0):

`insert` method takes a DBObject.

```
BasicDBObject document= new BasicDBObject();
document.put("name", "mkyong");
document.put("age", 30);
table1.insert(document);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`BasicDBList`](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/BasicDBList.html):

```
BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
document.put("name", "mkyong");
document.put("age", 30);

BasicDBList documentList = new BasicDBList();
documentList.add(document);

DBCollection table1 = db.getCollection("user");
table1.insert(documentList.get(0));
System.out.println("Collection Inserted successfully");
```